# Trying to edit value of TextView on LongClick -- Almost working

Tags: java, android

I have two elements (TextView) in my XML layout that when a LongClick is pressed it will prompt the user to enter in a new value and then when the DONE button is clicked it should show the newly inputed value to the tvScoreHome using setText().

When I do a Long Click on the mentioned element the edit field and keyboard appear as expected.  However, it won't allow me to type anything.  When I type something it nothing shows up (but the device vibrates as if a button was pressed) and when the DONE button is clicked it vibrates as well but it does not exit the keyboard and show anything in the tvScoreHome element.

Any ideas why?

```
    // set the onLongClickListener for tvScoreHome
    tvScoreHome.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            final EditText userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            userInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imm.showSoftInput(userInput, 0);
            tvScoreHome.setText( userInput.getText() );
            userInput.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the user a chance to input some text before copying the data and hiding the EditText.
Remove these two lines from your listener:

```
tvScoreHome.setText( userInput.getText() );
userInput.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Perhaps you could use an OnFocusChangeListener to run these two lines when `userInput` loses focus.

Comment: Can you tell me how to "listen" for the DONE key to be pressed?  I can find a lot of things for hardware keyboards but not the softinput.  I found one thing but when I try to create userInput.onEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() { the "onEditorActionListener" underlines red and it won't work.  I need to basically intercept the DONE key and execute code on this action.

Comment: The OnEditorActionListener is what you want but you add it to an EditText with [`setOnEditorActionListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29)